Moss Rose indoor growing
My porch is shade - I have a window sill in the house that gets sun till around 3 pm.  Will the moss rose get enough sun on the window sill inside my apt?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Moss roses tend to bloom for three or four months in the best of conditions and are not considered house plants. They require at least eight hours of direct sun per day and appreciate more sun than that. If your windows contain UV blockers then they also may not get the exact wavelengths they need.
